# How do I zoom with Ctrl instead of Alt on Windows in Adobe CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, windows, zoom

In Windows, the standard scroll-wheel zoom key is Ctrl. Pretty much everything follows this standard, including all web browsers, Word, Explorer, even Adobe Reader. Except Adobe Creative Cloud software (Illustrator, Photoshop, InDesign, etc.). It uses the Alt key instead.

This drives me nuts. Switching between all of these programs has my fingers in a frazzle. I keep using the wrong key in the wrong program.

To make matters worse, I also use Macintosh PCs on a daily basis (school vs home), and they use Alt to zoom. I could deal with the differences between MacOS and Windows just fine, except Adobe CC on Windows has to come in and throw a spanner in the works.

**Is there a way to scroll-wheel zoom with Ctrl in Adobe CC software on Windows, instead of Alt?**

Comment: You could download AutoHotKey and add theese lines to your script:
; Map Ctrl+Wheel to do Alt+Wheel for Adobe Illustrator to act like Affinity
#IfWinActive ahk_class illustrator
 ^WheelUp::!WheelUp
 ^WheelDown::!WheelDown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you got 3 options:

1. There's the Zoom with scroll wheel, so you can zoom just by using the scroll wheel.
2. There's the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> + mouse click zooming (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> for zooming out).
3. ...and the same thing as the previous method, except instead of a mouse click, you mouse drag sideways with the mouse while pressing down those same modifier keys. Also works if you switch to the zoom tool (<kbd>Z</kbd>), if you're not a fan of modifier keys at all

Comment: I have since discovered that Adobe calls #3 "Animated Zoom" in Illustrator and "Scrubby zoom" in Photoshop. There is an option in the Illustrator Settings under "GPU Performance" (of all places) to disable it. For Googlers.

Comment: What is Cmd+Space in Windows (as original question asks about)?

Comment: @NetMage, that would be: Ctrl+Space (typically any shortcut with Cmd translates to Ctrl on Windows)

Answer (score 4):

The only way I think you can do this is through Autohotkey. It’s a bit of work, but worth the effort. You have to first install Autohotkey. And then run a script on your background. For me it is always running on my background.

For a guide to Autohotkey look [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).

Make a script with this code. It does the following: When you are working in Indesign, the middle mouse button lets you move the page, as if you were pressing space and left mouse button. It also changes Ctrl scroll to Alt scroll.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class indesign
;Middle mouse button moves the page
    MButton::
    Send {Space Down}{LButton Down}
    Keywait, MButton
    Send {LButton Up}{Space Up}
    Return
;Map Ctrl+Wheel to do Alt+Wheel
    ^WheelUp::!WheelUp
    ^WheelDown::!WheelDown
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: For v2:
`#HotIf WinActive("ahk_class indesign")
;Middle mouse button moves the page
    MButton::
{
    Send "{Space Down}{LButton Down}"
    Keywait "MButton"
    Send "{LButton Up}{Space Up}"
    Return
}
;Map Ctrl+Wheel to do Alt+Wheel
    ^WheelUp::!WheelUp
    ^WheelDown::!WheelDown
#HotIf`

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem.
Edit > Preferences > Tools > Check the item "Zoom with Scroll Wheel"
Now you changed <kbd>Alt</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to zoom in/out.
That's it.
version: Photoshop CC 2019

Comment: This worked for me on Photoshop! My only problem, now, is with with Premiere! :- (

Comment: This is the answer for me

Answer (score -1):

If you go to 'Edit → Keyboard shortcuts' you can set your own keys.

Comment: That works for regular shortcuts. But Alt+Mouse Wheel is not a regular shortcut. It's not listed there (I should have mentioned this in the question), and I was looking for an alternative way. I'm not too hopeful, to be honest.